# Strange performance test results with different write concerns in MongoDB + C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to test the performance of **MongoDB** before actually putting it to use. I'm trying to see how many documents can I update per second. I'm using C# (Mono + Ubuntu) MongoDB Driver v1.9 and MongoDB v2.4.6.

I believe one of the most effective MongoDB parameters on write performance is `Write Concern`. As it is stated in [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/), the most relaxed value for write concern would be `-1`, then `0` and finally `1` is the slowest one.

After searching I found that I can set write concerns in C# embedded in connection string like this:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost/?w=-1");
```

Here are the results of me playing around with different values for `w`:

1. Fastest results are achieved when I set `w` to `1`!
2. Setting `w=0` is slower than `w=1` 28 times!
3. `w=-1` will lead to an exception thrown with error message `W value must be greater than or equal to zero`!

Does anyone have any explanations on these results? Am I doing anything wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

I think it is necessary to set the test procedure maybe there's something hidden within it. So here it goes:

I've got a database with 100M documents in a single collection. Each document is created like this using mongo shell:

```
{ "counter" : 0, "last_update" : new Date() }
```

Here's the output of `db.collection.stats();`:

```
{
    "ns" : "test.collection",
    "count" : 100000100,
    "size" : 6400006560,
    "avgObjSize" : 64.0000015999984,
    "storageSize" : 8683839472,
    "numExtents" : 27,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 5769582448,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3251652432,
        "last_update_1" : 2517930016
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Using **Mono 3.2.1** in **Ubuntu 12.04** I've written a **C#** project which connects to **MongoDB** and tries to update the documents like this:

```
FindAndModifyArgs args = new FindAndModifyArgs();
args.SortBy = SortBy.Ascending("last_update");
args.Update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.last_update, DateTime.Now);
args.Fields = Fields.Include(new string[] { "counter", "_id" });
var m = collection.FindAndModify(args);

Entity ent = m.GetModifiedDocumentAs<Entity>();
var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Id, ent.Id);
var update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.counter, ent.counter+1);
collection.Update(query, update);
```

To summarize what this piece of code does; it selects the oldest `last_update` and while it sets the `last_update` to current date, it also increments its counter (update happens in two steps).

I ran this code 10k for each of four different types of `Write Concerns`, `w=-1`, `w=0`, `w=1` and `w=1&j=true`. While `w=-1` throws an exception and gives out no results, here are the results for the rest of them:

[image]

Since the figure is a little hard to read, here're the same results in numbers:

```
            w=-1    w=0                 w=1                 w=1&j=true
Average     N/A     244.0948611492      7064.5143923477     238.1846428156
STDEV       N/A     1.7787457992        511.892765742       21.0230097306
```

And the question is: Does anyone have any explanations why `w=0` is much slower than `w=1` and why `w=-1` is not supported?

**[UPDATE]**

I've also tested [`RequestStart`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#requeststart-requestdone-methods) in my code like this:

```
using (server.RequestStart(database)) {
    FindAndModifyArgs args = new FindAndModifyArgs();
    args.SortBy = SortBy.Ascending("last_update");
    args.Update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.last_update, DateTime.Now);
    args.Fields = Fields.Include(new string[] { "counter", "_id" });
    var m = collection.FindAndModify(args);

    Entity ent = m.GetModifiedDocumentAs<Entity>();
    var query = Query<Entity>.EQ(e => e.Id, ent.Id);
    var update = Update<Entity>.Set(e => e.counter, ent.counter+1);
    collection.Update(query, update);
}
```

It had no significant effect on any of the results, what so ever.

Comment: The latest release is 1.8.2, you should verify which version you really have. I don't know if the `w=n` syntax is supported, but since I find connection strings to be are a weird anti-pattern, I'd suggest you use sth like `var collection = db.GetCollection("Foo", WriteConcern.Acknowledged);` for instance. The `WriteConcern` class allows very fine-grained control. Finally, for any performance measurement, make sure the connection pool is warm, the number of operations is significant, and you're measuring using `Stopwatch` or `QueryPerformanceCounter`, never with the `DateTime` class

Comment: Where can I find the version of my MongoDB C# driver? I downloaded the source code from github less than a month ago so I'm sure that it's not that old but it would be great if I could find the exact version number.

Answer (score 0):

To address the `w=-1` error, you may want to use the [`WriteConcern.Unacknowledged` property](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/273ceba2-beb8-02cc-4ce3-4d28324a54f1.htm) directly.

Your test code might be running into consistency problems. Look into [RequestStart/RequestDone](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#requeststart-requestdone-methods) to put the query onto the same connection. Per the documentation:

> An example of when this might be necessary is when a series of Inserts are called in rapid succession with a WriteConcern of w=0, and you want to query that data is in a consistent manner immediately thereafter (with a WriteConcern of w=0, the writes can queue up at the server and might not be immediately visible to other connections

Aphyr did [a good blog post](http://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb) on how well various settings of MongoDB's write concern effect its approximation of consistency. It may help you troubleshoot this issue.

Finally, you can find your driver version in [build.ps1](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/v1.8.3/build.ps1)

Comment: Thanks for the post but `WriteConcern.Unacknowledged` is not equal to `w=-1`. Unacknowledged is equal to `w=0`. `w=-1` is called `errors ignored` mode which I can not find in `WriteConcern` class. I will look into the rest of your suggestions and let you know how they went.